# best introductory simple readable undergraduate book for algebraic geometry

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, book-recommendation

I like to study algebraic geometry and what is the best introductory simple readable undergraduate book for it?

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/35288/undergraduate-roadmap-to-algebraic-geometry

Answer (score 1):

Reid's undergraduate algebraic geometry is a great book.